# How to run two commands in one line in shell script in ggsci command interpreter

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

How can I execute two commands in ggsci in one go?

I want to login using `dblogin` and then, in the same shell, I want to run the `info all` command.

```
echo "dblogin userid abc password 123" | echo "info all"
```

This pipe doesn't work.

Comment: Are you somehow trying to pipe that to ggsci? Could you show the complete (shell?) script?

Comment: The pipe doesn't work because the second `echo` doesn't read its standard input and the first `echo`'s output is lost.  Have you tried `{ echo "dblogin userid abc password 123"; echo "info all"; } | ggsci`?  This is one of many ways of generating two lines of input and piping it to `ggsci`.  If you need a separator between the commands, you can add that to the `echo`ed information.

Comment: It says its unable to connect the database with the username i provide . check privileges whereas when I run the same command directly from ggsci it works

Comment: Any other suggestions .. This approach doesn`t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
echo obey "obey_cmds.txt" | ./ggsci
```

Where your obey file contains the `dblogin` and `info all` commands.

I do something like this in my scripts, with the script generating the obey file on the fly, and then executing it.

For example, given this obey file, `obey_cmds.txt`:

```
dblogin userid ggsadmin password s3cr3t
info all
```

Execution looks like this:

```
$ echo obey /apps/ggsadmin/goldengate/monitoring/scripts/obey_cmds.txt | $GG_HOME/ggsci

Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter for Oracle
Version 11.2.1.0.1 OGGCORE_11.2.1.0.1_PLATFORMS_120423.0230
AIX 5L, ppc, 64bit (optimized), Oracle 11g on Apr 23 2012 05:03:51

Copyright (C) 1995, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.



GGSCI (aixorad02) 1>
GGSCI (aixorad02) 2> dblogin userid ggsadmin password s3cr3t

Successfully logged into database.

GGSCI (aixorad02) 3> info all

Program     Status      Group       Lag at Chkpt  Time Since Chkpt

MANAGER     RUNNING
EXTRACT     RUNNING     EQBTTC      00:00:00      00:00:01
EXTRACT     RUNNING     PQBTTC      00:00:00      00:00:01


GGSCI (aixorad02) 4> exit
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there some reason you need to this on one line?

A here document works fine for me

```
ggs> ggsci <<HERE
> DBLOGIN USERID abc, PASSWORD 123
> INFO ALL
> HERE

Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter for Oracle
Version 11.2.1.0.6_02 16874194 OGGCORE_11.2.1.0.7_PLATFORMS_130530.0600.1_FBO
Solaris, sparc, 64bit (optimized), Oracle 11g on Jun  5 2013 01:15:20

Copyright (C) 1995, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.



GGSCI (foo01) 1>
Successfully logged into database.

GGSCI (foo01) 2>
Program     Status      Group       Lag at Chkpt  Time Since Chkpt

MANAGER     RUNNING
REPLICAT    ABENDED     PERF1REP    00:00:00      01:54:59


GGSCI (foo01) 3>
ggs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but on my plate and using the likes of this within slightly wider scopes:

-- sample script snip

```
pushd .
cd $GG_HOME
./ggsci -s <<EOF>>gg.out
start manager
start extract *
start rep *
send *,status
EOF
gg_retval=$?
popd
```

Then either handle via the retval return or your output file.  Obviously there's all kinds that you could do.  Careful with the snip.  I just shoved examples in - may not deliver the return values or output files that you're looking for.

oh, and parting shot : handy aliases for repeat ggsci tasking

```
alias cdgg='pushd . ; cd $GG_HOME'
alias gg='cdgg;./ggsci;popd'
```

- all the above is in sh/bash..